# Different targets in XCode

Tags: xcode

I have 2 targets in my XCode project. I have a bunch of file having their target set to target 1. I would like to set their target to target 2 as well, is there a script i can run that achieves this purpose

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a script for this - just select all the files, do a Get Info, select the Targets tab, and then check the second target.

Comment: I want to do it programmatically, not feasible of many targets and different dependencies among them.

Comment: @user265260: OK - you might want to make this clearer in your question, as it states that you have just 2 targets.